# Having images in a picker for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I'm writing an iPhone app in which I have a double component picker. One side has the 13 different card values (ace, 2, 3, 4, etc.) and the other should have images for the four suits (spades, hearts, diamonds, clubs). I dragged the four .png files into the folder.

Can anyone tell me why this code doesn't work? I'm almost exactly following an example from class.

```
UIImage *spades = [UIImage imageNamed:@"spades.png"];
UIImage *hearts = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hearts.png"];
UIImage *diamonds = [UIImage imageNamed:@"diamonds.png"];
UIImage *clubs = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clubs.png"];

UIImageView *spadesView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:spades];
UIImageView *heartsView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:hearts];
UIImageView *diamondsView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:diamonds];
UIImageView *clubsView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:clubs];

NSArray *suitsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: spadesView, heartsView, diamondsView, clubsView, nil];
self.suits = suitsArray;
```

When I just try to do this (below), it works.

```
NSArray *suitsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Spades", @"Hearts", @"Diamonds", @"Clubs", nil];
self.suits = suitsArray;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: You do not specify a frame for the image views.

Comment: FreeAsInBeer, sorry I didn't specify... I don't get an error. The simulator loads but then immediately crashes.

Comment: Radek, I'm not sure what you mean by specifying a frame.

Comment: How does it crash? What exception do you get?

Comment: Maybe too big images ? You have to release your UIImageView after putting them in an NSArray, then release you array is your suits variable is a retained property.

Comment: Indeed, we would need to know what kind of error you get. Might be a bad access... Does anything special happen in the setter method for suits?

Answer (score 0):

Try that, it could do the work :

```
- (void)populateSuitsArray
{
    NSMutableArray *suitsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

    UIImage *spades = [UIImage imageNamed:@"spades.png"];
    UIImageView *spadesView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:spades];
    [suitsArray addObject:spadesView];
    [spadesView release];

    UIImage *hearts = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hearts.png"];
    UIImageView *heartsView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:hearts];
    [suitsArray addObject:spadesView];
    [spadesView release];

    UIImage *diamonds = [UIImage imageNamed:@"diamonds.png"];
    UIImageView *diamondsView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:diamonds];
    [suitsArray addObject:diamondsView];
    [diamondsView release];

    UIImage *clubs = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clubs.png"];
    UIImageView *clubsView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:clubs];
    [suitsArray addObject:clubsView];
    [clubsView release];

    self.suits = suitsArray;
    [suitsArray release]; // According if your suits is a retained property
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the code. It still doesn't seem to work. I get no errors, simulator opens, but the app doesn't even open. I'm starting to think the problem might be with my .png files, though I seem to be following the 57x57 pixel specifications. Any ideas what else can be wrong with the images?